# Swift 3.0: How to save a user's image in the app from an imagePicker

Tags: ios, swift3, uiimageview, xcode8, uiimagepickercontroller

I am trying to have a user choose an image from their gallery or camera, then upload it to the app. This works, but the only problem is that it doesn't save it in the app. As soon as the user closes the app, the image that the user chose disappears. I also do not have any save function because i don't know how to implement one.

I am using Xcode 8.3.2 in Swift 3.0. Here is the code below:

```
    import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    @IBAction func chooseImage(_ sender: Any) {

        let imagePickerController = UIImagePickerController()
        imagePickerController.delegate = self

        let actionSheet = UIAlertController(title: "Photo Source", message: "Choose a source", preferredStyle: .actionSheet)

        actionSheet.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Camera", style: .default, handler: { (action:UIAlertAction) in

            if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(.camera) {
                imagePickerController.sourceType = .camera
                self.present(imagePickerController, animated: true, completion: nil)
            }else{
                print("Camera not available")
            }


        }))

        actionSheet.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Photo Library", style: .default, handler: { (action:UIAlertAction) in
            imagePickerController.sourceType = .photoLibrary
            self.present(imagePickerController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }))

        actionSheet.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: nil))

        self.present(actionSheet, animated: true, completion: nil)


    }

    func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
        let image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as! UIImage

        imageView.image = image

        picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(_ picker: UIImagePickerController) {
        picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }





    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


}
```

Comment: If you are not using any database, then simply use nsusedefault to save image or any data locally on device. and retrieve anywhere within app

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remember to save image you need to store image as NSData

```
      // Code to store image
     let defaults = UserDefaults.standard

   //  To save as data:

  //   From StoryBoard, if you want to save "image" data on the imageView of 
  //   MainStoryBoard, following codes will work.

     let image = UIImagePNGRepresentation(imageView.image!) as NSData? 
    defaults.set(image, forKey: "test")  // saving image into userdefault


     // for retrieving the image 

   if (UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "test") as? NSData) != nil {
        let photo = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "test") as! NSData
        img2.image = UIImage(data: photo as Data) // img2 set your imageview on which you want photo to appear

        // Now you can set img2.image
    }
```

Edited

How to use in your code

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, 
    didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
     let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
     let image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as! UIImage

     imageView.image = image
    let saveImage = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image!) as NSData? 
    defaults.set(saveImage, forKey: "test")  // saving image into userdefault


     picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

And in your view did load use retrieving method
If the image exist and in nsdata format then only it will show save image. Thats it.

Comment: Variable with getter/setter cannot have an initial value:
Expected declaration
Use of unresolved identifier 'intFileRef'
Use of unresolved identifier 'defaults'
Computed property must have an explicit type
Insert ': <# Type #>'
'let' declarations cannot be computed properties
Consecutive declarations on a line must be separated by ';'
Insert ';'
Use of unresolved identifier 'println'
Use of unresolved identifier 'defaults'
 Use of unresolved identifier 'intFileRef'

Comment: Okay, gonna post new syntax for swift 3 
it is correct code for doing so.

Comment: I edited my asnwer and should work. Use save method where you want and call method where you want to show images. Hope it helps :)

Comment: Please check my answers. I added lot of comments and should work now

Comment: Alright thank you. I am just confused on where i would put this code. Do i put it in the viewDidLoad()?

Comment: No, Used the code to save image inside this method didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo. Add use the code to retieve image in view did load if you want to show the same image already next time on load. On anyother screen at anypoint you want.

Comment: I have this error showing at defaults.setObject("test", forKey: image) : Cannot convert value of type 'NSData?' to expected argument type 'String'

Comment: sorry set wrong key value pair. Please check my updated answer

Comment: First, thank you for your persistence in helping me. Second, the app crashes when i choose an image. let image = UIImagePNGRepresentation(imageView.image!) as NSData? : Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0). I think it is because i replaced img2 with imageView since it was throwing an error.

Comment: My apologies if i was not clear enough. All i am trying to do as have the user take an image and have that image appear always on the view controller unless they replace with another image.

Comment: Please see updated reply and If you have any other problem and post new question so I can reply there. But hopefully it should work now

Answer (score 0):

You can save image in your document directory with below function

```
func saveImageDocumentDirectory(tempImage:UIImage){

    let documentsDirectoryURL = try! FileManager().url(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: true)
    let fileURL = documentsDirectoryURL.appendingPathComponent("ImageName.png")
        do {
            try UIImagePNGRepresentation(tempImage)?.write(to: fileURL)
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
}
```

To retrieve Image you can use

```
func getImage()->URL?{

    let documentsDirectoryURL = try! FileManager().url(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: true)
     let fileURL = documentsDirectoryURL.appendingPathComponent("ImageName.png")

    if FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: fileURL.path){
        return fileURL
    }else{
        return nil
    }
}
```

You can use any name you like and store image with different name to store multiple image.

Comment: I added these two functions, but the user uploaded image still disappears when i close the app and reopen it.

Comment: you will get url from the getImage() function, you need to get image from it

Comment: How do i change the url path to match the user's image from the imagePicker?

Comment: imagePickerControllerDidCancel ??? it will get called when user taps on cancel button

Comment: you need to call saveImageDocumentDirectory() in didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo

Comment: No, i did not put it inside that function, after the function.

Comment: You need to pass image you are getting from picker in the saveImageDocumentDirectory()

Comment: I need some help on how to do that as i am very unfamiliar with this. Can you please take a look at my code above?

Comment: you need to call function below imageView.image = image code